# Django Rest Framework how to filter nested data?

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to filter the nested data, and these are my serializers and views

Models :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_identity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    place_birth = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    no_hp = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'employee'

class Penalty(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    doc = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'penalty'
```

Serializers :

```
class PenaltySerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee_identity = serializers.CharField(source="employee.employee_identity")
    month = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    year = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_month(self,obj):
        value_start_date = obj.start_date
        month_value = value_start_date.strftime("%b")
        return bulan_value
    def get_year(self,obj):
        value_start_date = obj.start_date
        year_value = value_start_date.strftime("%Y")
        return year_value
    class Meta:
        model = Penalty
        fields = ('id','employee','employee_identity','type','start_date','end_date','month','year') 

class EmployeeSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    penalty = PenaltySerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:  
        model = Employee
        fields =  ('employee_identity','full_name','penalty')
```

Views:

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PegawaiSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get','head']
    pagination_class = LimitPagination

class PenaltyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    queryset = Penalty.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PenaltySerializer
    http_method_names = ['get','head']
    pagination_class = LimitPagination
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['employee','type']
    search_fields = ['^start_date']

class DetailDataEmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get','head']
    pagination_class = LimitPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['id','employee_identity']
```

the result I have without date filter

```
 "results": [
         {
             "id": 13886,
             "employee_identity": "A3014",
             "full_name": "AAAA",
             "penalty": []
         },
         {
             "id": 13887,
             "employee_identity": "A3015",
             "full_name": "BBB",
             "penalty": [
               {
                     "id": 1,
                     "employee": 20924,
                     "employee_identity": "A3015",
                     "type": "low",
                     "start_date": "2021-01-01",
                     "end_date": "2021-01-02",
                     "month": "Jan",
                     "year": "2021"
                 },
                 {
                     "id": 2,
                     "employee": 20924,
                     "employee_identity": "A3015",
                     "type": "low",
                     "start_date": "2021-02-11",
                     "end_date": "2021-02-12",
                     "month": "Feb",
                     "year": "2021"
                 }
              ]
         }
```

And the result I want if I filter the data by date (ex: filter date : 2021-01)

```
"results": [
            {
                "id": 13886,
                "employee_identity": "A3015",
                "full_name": "BBB",
                "penalty": [
                  {
                        "id": 1,
                        "employee": 20924,
                        "employee_identity": "A3015",
                        "type": "low",
                        "start_date": "2021-01-01",
                        "end_date": "2021-01-02",
                        "month": "Jan",
                        "year": "2021"
                    }
                 ]
            }
```

I can make the result based on DjangoFilterBackend in DetailDataEmployeeViewSet but I don't know how to result penalty data by date. How do i make it happen ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy *solution* is to extend [filter_queryset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering) method of the ViewSet

```
class DetailDataEmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get','head']
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['id','employee_identity']

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date", None)

        if start_date is not None:
            print(start_date)
            queryset = queryset.filter(penalty__start_date=start_date)

        return queryset
```

usage:

> GET /employee/?start_date=2021-02-27

Comment: thanks for your answer, but after I filter with 2021-01 , the data in penalty which have start_date 2021-02 also show up. I'm using penalty__start_date__contains=start_date